# How to remove "-" from string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove "-" from a whole string?

I am using this line which works but only for the first "-", it doesn't remove the other "-".

image name: cropped-Journal-trend-02.png

```
 imagePath: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html().replace(('-', '')
```

Comment: var imagePath = "cropped-Journal-trend-02.png";
var newImagepath = imagePath .replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'),"");

Can you pls try this. It will remove all - from your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `g` modifier that is global.It does not return after first match

```
imagePath: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html().replace(/-/g, '')
```

Comment: it's working.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
imagePath: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html().replace(/-/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imagePath = "cropped-Journal-trend-02.png";
var newImagepath = imagePath.replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'),"");
```

Can you pls try this. It will remove all - from your string

Comment: i also try this not remove.@user6044627

Comment: It will work. Open your developer tool and paste 
  var imagePath = "cropped-Journal-trend-02.png";
  var newImagepath = imagePath.replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'),"");
print newImagepath . This will not have any - sign.